# failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Tags: php

In this code :

```
$path = "C:\NucServ\www\vv\static\arrays\news.php";
  $fp = fopen($path, "w");
  if(fwrite($fp=fopen($path,"w"),$text))
  {
    echo "ok";
  }
  fclose($fp);
```

I have this error message:

```
failed to open stream: Invalid argument
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your backslashes is converted into special chars by PHP. For instance, `...arrays\news.php` gets turned into

```
   ...arrays
   ews.php
```

You should escape them like this:

```
$path = "C:\\NucServ\\www\\vv\\static\\arrays\\news.php";
```

Or use singles, like this:

```
$path = 'C:\NucServ\www\vv\static\arrays\news.php';
```

Also, your `if` is messed up. You shouldn't `fopen` the file again. Just use your `$fp` which you already have.

Comment: Does this still apply?

Answer (score -2):

1. path error:

   ```
   $path = 'C:/NucServ/www/vv/static/arrays/news.php';
   ```
2. file lock:

   ```
   user file_get_contents replace fopen
   ```