# Make a path work both on linux and Windows

Tags: php, windows, linux

How can I make sure that this path:

```
new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(APPLICATION_PATH . '\logs\app.log')
```

works both on linux and on windows?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In Linux, the path separator is `/`. In Windows, it is either `\` or `/`. So just use forward slashes and you will be fine.

```
APPLICATION_PATH . '/logs/app.log'
```

Comment: but when i then print my path on a windows system i get: K:\project345\application/logs/app.log

Comment: @sanders, That's not a problem. Windows understands that path. In Windows you can mix forward and backward slashes in a single path.

Comment: I've seen this being said before but it seems to conflict with the information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410354/failed-to-open-stream-invalid-argument

Comment: @Matt, that's a different issue. In that question someone was not escaping backslashes in their string, and `\n` was being converted to a newline. If you are going to use backslashes, you have to escape them properly. That's a basic php issue though, so it's not directly related to this.

Comment: Also note that the problem in that question only arose because they were using double-quotes, where `\n` is interpreted that way. If you use single quotes (the the OP did in the example here) then `\n` is not interpreted in any special way, and the literal works fine as-is.

Answer (score 36):

You can also use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant instead of `\` or `/`.
Usually you'll want to redefine it to have shorter name, like

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$filename = APP . DS . 'logs' . DS . 'file.txt';
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to communicate two or more app of your site, this trick will serve you much

```
$ Document_root = realpath ( \ filter_input ( INPUT_SERVER , ' DOCUMENT_ROOT '));
```

this is to convert the route you back real path and then just have to navigate between directories with the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR without worrying about the operating system installed on your machine or web server

Answer (score 0):

Just realpath() is seems to be enough

[Example #2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)