# Multi platform path in php

Tags: php, linux, windows

I have a path in php, that looks like this:

```
$command = 'cd ' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/../src/python && python3 preview.py'
```

On my Ubuntu machine that creates a command that look like this and can be executed:

`cd /var/www/html/project/../src/python && python3 preview.py`

However, if I run the same script on my windows machine, the path looks like this:

`cd C:\Projects\project/../src/python && python3 preview.py`

Is there a way to make it so it can be called on both platforms equally? I found this but it does not seem to work. [Make a path work both on linux and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178263/make-a-path-work-both-on-linux-and-windows)

Any hint appreciated

Comment: You can try: `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Comment: hope this can help:-https://superuser.com/questions/111825/a-command-line-or-batch-cmd-to-concatenate-multiple-files

Comment: Many do `define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);` and then just use `DS`

Comment: Any returned error? Why not `python3 /path/to/script.py` instead of running two comands?