# PHP file copy not working on absolute directory

Tags: php

I have written a little PHP file, that creates a new folder and is supposed to copy a file from a constant location to this newly created folder. As the function is supposed to always work, no matter from which location on the server it is executed, I would like to use a absolute path to the file to copy.

Now everything is working as I want to, except, when I use an absolute path to the file. The file exists, and the folder has gotten the same permissions. I am on a Windows machine for testing, so permissions should propably not be the issue.

`copy('/roessle/ressources/index.php', $newDirInd);`

the folder roessle is a folder in the root folder of my Apache webserver, so one layer below the directory I would land in when just type in localhost.

now what is wrong with that path?
the file exists, and I have checked for typos like 100 times, but it just won't work.

Comment: `/...` does asuredly *not* exist on a Windows machine.

Comment: just checked with \ does not work either

Comment: You are still missing the drive letter. Something along the lines of `C:\roessle\....`.

Comment: so you need to go this absolute?
thought it was the same thing as with href to absolute paths.

Comment: PHP runs on the server and has to use which ever file path structure the operating system dictates.

Comment: works, case closed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a path work both on linux and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178263/make-a-path-work-both-on-linux-and-windows)

Comment: @JohannesZeiser then delete your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an not an absolute path in your filesystem. Try this:

```
copy($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/roessle/ressources/index.php', $newDirInd);
```