# require_once(); Invalid argument error

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [failed to open stream: Invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410354/failed-to-open-stream-invalid-argument)

```
// Define the core paths
// Define them as absolute paths to make sure that require_once works as expected

// DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is a PHP pre-defined constant
// (\ for Windows, / for Unix)
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : 

define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'C:'.DS.'wamp'.DS.'www'.DS.'photo_gallery');

defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

// load config file first
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'config.php');

// load basic functions next so that everything after can use them
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'functions.php');

// load core objects
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'session.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');

// load database-related classes
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'user.php');
```

Whenever, i tried to run this code by typing in my address bar localhost/photo_gallery/public/admin/index.php. It will display an error like this:

> Warning: require_once(\C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes\config.php):
>   failed to openstream: Invalid argument in
>   C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes \initialize.php on line 16.
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '\C: \wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes\config.php'(include_path='.;C:\php\pear')
>   in C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes\initialize.php on line 16

Please, tell me what to do? Am a beginner startup webdesigner and am getting stuck with this fatal error.

Comment: Use define instead of defined

Comment: so many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759360/fatal-error-require-once-failed-opeining-required-c-wamp-www-photo-gallery, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759794/require-once-failed-to-openstream-invalid-argument-in-c-wamp-www-photo-gall#13759794

Comment: The answer you were given explains your error perfectly. We don't spoonfeed people, the error is that the file doesn't exist. Now deal with it however you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

`DS` is extra in following line:

define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'C:'.DS.'wamp'.DS.'www'.DS.'photo_gallery');

Please remove it so it become

```
define('SITE_ROOT', 'C:'.DS.'wamp'.DS.'www'.DS.'photo_gallery');
```

use define instead  defined