# file_put_contents Failed to open stream: invalid argument

Tags: php

I have this code written in PHP, im using zend server on win 7 as localhost.

```
<?php

$dir = $_POST['link'];
// Create DOM from URL or file

require_once 'library/simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html($dir);

foreach($html->find('img') as $element){

  $image = $element->src;
  $imglink = $dir . $image;
  $filename = $element->src;
  $parsed_url = parse_url($filename, PHP_URL_PATH);
  $basename = basename($filename).PHP_EOL;

  $filenameOut = __DIR__ . "/images/" . $basename;

    $pos = strpos($image, 'data:image');
    if ($pos===false){
     $parsing = parse_url($filename, PHP_URL_HOST);

        if ($parsing != NULL){
            file_put_contents($filenameOut, file_get_contents($image));
            }
        else{
        file_put_contents($filenameOut, file_get_contents($imglink));
            }
     }

    }
  ?>
```

And it gives me this error

```
file_put_contents(C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs/images/chrome-48.png ): failed to open stream: Invalid argument
```

Ive tried putting ways i've read from other questions from this site, but doesnt work.

Comment: Notice the backspaces (watch full explanation [here][1])


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410354/failed-to-open-stream-invalid-argument

Comment: Remove PHP_EOL from this line: $basename = basename($filename).PHP_EOL;
I dont get why even You use this there.

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_get_contents($image))` or `var_dump(file_get_contents($imglink))` tell you?

Comment: @user3136936 It comes from a variable so I don't think that is the problem

Comment: @PeeHaa the '$image' and '$imglink' are the data to write, i created two variable because ive noticed that some websies uses CDN for their images while some static websites use their own server for the images. And when i run them just what youve told, it shows some weird random symbols.

Comment: That was not the question in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558255/file-put-contents-failed-to-open-stream-invalid-argument?noredirect=1#comment38036469_24558255) :-)

Comment: Thank you guys for the awesome participations, but while i was reading  stuffs from the internet, i think the problem is relates to the fact that i am running this from a localhost server on windows, when i uploaded this to a live server, it just works.

Comment: @PeeHaa sorry, i was just explaining the functions of the variables, anyway, the 'var_dump(file_get_contents($image))' and 'var_dump(file_get_contents($imglink))' just shows some random weird symbols when i accessed the php file from the browser.