# PHP error when trying to access Factual API

Tags: php, factual

I am using WAMP for my PHP framework. I am trying to test this code

```
<?php
require_once "C:\wamp\www\factual-php-driver-master\Factual.php";
$factual= new Factual("/*API Key*/","/*API Secret*/");

$query= new FactualQuery;
$query->limit(3);
$res= $factual->fetch("places", $query);
print_r($res->getData());
?>
```

The PATH to my Factual.php file is absolutely correct but the file returns the following errors

**Warning: require_once(C:\wamp\wwwactual-php-driver-master\Factual.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\foodmeets\restaurants.php on line 2**

**Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\wwwactual-php-driver-master\Factual.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\foodmeets\restaurants.php on line 2**

Please note I had performed the testing of the PHP install environment using the command

```
php -f test.php yourFactualKey yourFactualSecret [logfile]
```

as mentioned in the Factual Driver(V3) for PHP on Github(https://github.com/Factual/factual-php-driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to escape \f (The \f metacharacter is used to find a form feed character.)

```
require_once "C:\wamp\www\\factual-php-driver-master\Factual.php";
```

Comment: yes it is working now, but can you explain why this happened ?

Comment: actually C:\wamp\www\factual-php-driver-master\Factual.php, in this \factual-php-driver-master had \f which is metacharacter used to find a form feed character. In php we need to escape all such things by using extra backslash hence \\factual-php-driver-master.

Answer (score 0):

Your backslashes is converted into special chars by PHP. 
For instance, ...**arrays\news.php** gets turned into

...arrays

ews.php

You should escape them like this:

**$path = "C:\NucServ\www\vv\static\arrays\news.php";** 
Or use singles, like this:

**$path = 'C:\NucServ\www\vv\static\arrays\news.php';**

Also, your if is messed up. You shouldn't fopen the file again. Just use your $fp which you already have.

Source [failed to open stream: Invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410354/failed-to-open-stream-invalid-argument)