# How do I download and save images from url

Tags: php

I have this URL

```
'http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LBbpkomI7JQ/VnLmeFZANgI/AAAAAAAAWhc/MsdZjtxN0HQ/s0-Ic42/RCO001.jpg '
```

I tried to do some search and did this

```
$file = fopen("C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\script.txt", "r");
$links = array();

while (!feof($file)) {
$links[] = fgets($file);
}

fclose($file);

foreach($links as $num => $link)
{
echo "'".$link."'";
save_image("'".$link."'","'".$num."'".".jpg");

}

var_dump($links);
function save_image($inPath,$outPath)
{ //Download images from remote server
$in=    fopen($inPath, "rb");
$out=   fopen($outPath, "wb");
while ($chunk = fread($in,8192))
{
    fwrite($out, $chunk, 8192);
}
fclose($in);
fclose($out);
}
```

All urls are in my script.txt file so I am storing them in an array then calling each url one by one but it says

```
 failed to open stream: Invalid argument
```

Anything missing or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this implementation (works great for me):

```
<?php

$links = explode("\n", file_get_contents("C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\script.txt"));

foreach($links as $num => $link)
{
    echo $link . "\n";
    save_image($link, $num.".jpg");
}

function save_image($inPath, $outPath)
{
    $inPath = trim($inPath);
    if ($inPath != "") {
        file_put_contents($outPath, file_get_contents($inPath));
    }
}
```

assuming your script.txt looks like this

```
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LBbpkomI7JQ/VnLmeFZANgI/AAAAAAAAWhc/MsdZjtxN0HQ/s0-Ic42/RCO001.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
$file = fopen("C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\script.txt", "r");
```

Your backslashes might be converted into special chars by PHP, this could cause a problem, so
look at this topic:
[failed to open stream: Invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410354/failed-to-open-stream-invalid-argument)

**Second thing:**
It might be a problem with [**fopen** configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Edit your php.ini and set:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

You can check this value (it's probably false):

```
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));
```

You'll need to speak to your web host, or try another method. Mabye [CURL](http://php.net/curl) is enabled?

You should also check your [`display_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) and [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/error_reporting) values.  PHP should have complained loudly about being unable to open the URL.